# D3.js force layout slow in IE 9

Tags: internet-explorer, d3.js, force-layout

I am using d3.js and force layout for layouting .

I see that layouting happens fast in chrome and firefox but is very slow in IE

Answer (score 0):

IE9 has poor performance in SVG and some DOM operations that D3 utilizes. See:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/d3-js/IE9/d3-js/gNGpZxHgEmw/yKp-Ga--OuYJ
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/d3-js/XyHGuyenNrQ/kCM1F1wdOpYJ

And just more generally, search "IE9" on the d3js Google Groups:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/d3-js/IE9